# How can I find the n-gram of a sentence?

Tags: c++

I am given the test string of `helloworld` where I must find the n-gram of, specificed that it is `3`. Therefore, my code should give me the output of: 
`hel, ell, llo, low, owo, wor, orl, rld,`

The code I have written is the following:

```
vector<string> generate_ngrams(string w, size_t n) {
vector<string> ngrams;

for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ngrams.push_back(w.substr(i * n, n));

}

return ngrams;
```

The output I am getting with my code:
`hel, low, orl,`

How can I manipulate the code I have so far so that the for loop calls for some type of push back to the "e", for example, and then find the two letters after it, and continue doing that until it can't do it anymore?

Here is what is called in main also to see what is being thrown in:

```
  case 2:{
    string s;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');    
    getline(cin, s);
    auto v = generate_ngrams(s, n);
    copy (v.begin(), v.end(), oss);
    cout << endl;
    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n is size of substrs, not size of w.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= w.length() - n; ++i)
{
    ngrams.push_back(w.substr(i, n));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That brings me closer. Now the issue I am having is how do I make it so it outputs the last 3 letters? The output I am getting is `hel, ell, llo, low, owo, wor, orl,`

Comment: It should be `i <= w.length() - n`. Otherwise it'll skip the last three. Also there's a typo with length.